# JavaScript Slideshow with 4 images

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple slideshow.. something isn't quite right and I'm not sure what. For some reason the startSlideShow function is being called but not implementing the altering of the "position" variable...

```js
var timer = null;
var position = 0;
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.slide img');
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].src = 'dog' + i + '.jpg';

  var button = document.getElementById('control');
  button.onclick = run;

  function run() {
    if (timer == null) { //stopped or page has just loaded
      timer = setInterval(startSlideShow, 4000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer); //this stops animation
      timer = null;
    }

  };

  function startSlideShow() {
    position++;
    images[i].style.left = position + 'px';

  };
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="control">Stop/Start</button>
```

Comment: declare your functions outside for loop

Comment: Thats initially what I thought I should do but when I do delcare them outside the for loop I get an error "i" is not defined message in my startSlideShow function

Comment: after you declare them outside the loop you then need to call them from within the loop and pass in `i` as a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic that you were following is reversed. The loop of images should start with pressing of button where event listener on click need to be attached. Therefore function that iterates need to enclose the loop.
Try following code it uses IE6 syntax with arrow functions. Let me know if you need IE5 one but I guess you may easily figure out how to transform it if you need.

I've just refactored solution in order to behave like slideshow one :)

Here is working JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0t00oax8/

Please try following code

```
    var timer = null; 
    var position = 0;
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('.slide img');

    const showNextPic = () => {
           images[ (position > 0) ? (position-1) : 0 ].style = "display:none";
          if( position >= images.length){
             position = 0;
           }

           let imgName =  'dog' + position + '.jpg'
          images[position].src = imgName;
          images[position].alt = imgName;
          images[position].style = "display:block"
          position++;

    }

       var button = document.getElementById('control');

         button.addEventListener('click', () => {
         if (timer == null) { //stopped or page has just loaded
              timer = setInterval(showNextPic, 2000);
         }else {
             clearInterval(timer); //this stops animation
             timer = null;
          }    
       }) ;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it would be nice to explain any mistakes OP made so they can learn